# -bash: protoc: command not found

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I am using my mac Version :OSX El Capital 10.11.6
I tried this command

```
 protoc --version
```

its not working
and I did this steps :

```
1. brew uninstall --devel protobuf
2. brew link libtool
3. brew install --devel protobuf
```

and not working is there any other method?

Answer (score 3):

Try to do:

```
brew link --force --overwrite protobuf
```

and then check  --version again,
It might because brew didn't make symbolic link of protoc
it works to me